# HTML5 filesystem - save file on disk

Tags: html, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I wonder how I could save a file on disk in a specific folder. Currently, I use HTML5 filesystem API to save and store my information inside the browser. But I'd like to save them on disk and in the same directory as the file that I edit. And without the prompt window.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Chrome Apps can do this via the `chrome.fileSystem` API. There is a huge amount of information on the web about how to use that API, including extensive documentation from Google. A quick web search should get you what you need.

(Chrome Apps have a lot of APIs not available to ordinary web apps.)

Comment: It was around this API as I turned. But when I want to save my file, it always opens the window to ask me where I want to save my file. What I would like is to save my file without this window. But I have not found how to do it. Thank you very much for your answers. It is much appreciated!

Comment: @user1987480 You can't avoid this window entirely (the user has to explicitly allow you to access a folder), but you can retain the entry you obtained and use this folder later without re-confirmation.

Comment: To add to what Xan said, if the user chooses a directory one time, and then that entry is retained, directories and files within the tree rooted at the chosen directory can be created and accessed by the app with no further action by the user.

Answer (score 1):

This would be considered a security issue.  HTML5 only allows filesystems to be accessed from a protected area on your local drive controlled by the browser.

However, there are ways of storing data to this specified area temporarily or permanently.

window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, yourFile);
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT , 1024*1024, yourFile);

Comment: Yes I know for security restrictions. But in my case it is a Chrome application for ChromeOS. And it seems to me that there is a way to do this kind of thing. But I do not know how :)